# Matlab function not returning values

Tags: python, matlab

I have a problem which occurs when calculating option pricing using binomial model in Matlab.

[image]

The probem is: I don't know why this yields no outcome at all.

This is my original python code:

```
import numpy as np

def binom_tree_put(S0, r, sigma, K, T, N):
    dt = T/N
    u = np.exp(sigma*numpy.sqrt(dt))
    d = 1 / u
    p = (numpy.exp(r*dt)-d) / (u-d)

    price_tree = np.zeros([N+1, N+1])

    for i in range(N+1):
        for j in range(i+1):
            price_tree[j,i] = S0*(d**j)*(u**(i-j))

    option = np.zeros([N+1, N+1])
    option =[:, N] = np.maximum(numpy.zeros(N+1), price_tree[:,N]-K)

    for i in numpy.arange(N-1, -1, -1):
        for j in numpy.arange(0, i+1):
            option[j,i] + numpy.exp(-r*dt)*(p*option[j,i+1]+(1-p)*option[j+1,i+1])

    return option[0,0]
```

Comment: If you can, please try translating my python code into Matlab.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains the matlab -- not the python -- code

Comment: @LeonardLee: From Review: Please also add the MatLab code to the question, otherwise it might get deleted from Stack Overflow. This is also the reason why you get downvotes on your question. Please read this: [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you are running the script that entails the function. You need to call the function in order for it to return anything. Hence, in your command line you want to write

```
[dt,u,d,p,Pe] = EuroOp(...)
```